# Count with jquery size data-group value

Tags: jquery, count, size, each

I would like to know the number of the element that have value "3d"

```
var nbrnbr  = $('figure' ).size();
alert(nbr); // OK return XX
var nbr = $('figure[data-group="3d"]').size();
alert(nbr); // NOT ok return 0
```

Do I necessarily have to use each?

The number figure can change in DOM

Comment: My group can content multi value  data-groups='["wallpaper","3d"]'

Comment: An example of HTML markup would be great.

Comment: Check .length()... For larger loops .lenght() is preferred over .size()

Comment: Share a sample HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/su13jfmu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**jQuery *.length* method**

Try this:

You want to use ***.length*** as it is checking for the attribute.

Modify your code likewise:

```
var nbr = $('figure[data-group="3d"]').length;
alert(nbr);
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Dont work with   var nbr = $('figure[data-groups="3d"]').length; // => 0

Comment: Try:  alert($('[data-group="3d"]').length);

Comment: Why not try selecting using a common class name. Give a class (ex: 3dFigure) for all figures that are 3d. Then try alert( $('.3dFigure').length );

Comment: Did it work ? Did you try by adding  class name as mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes, adding the class its work. but I'd like to do with the group

Comment: So there will be multiple <img> tag within a <figure> tag and you have added data-group to the <figure> tag. Correct ?

Comment: OK then add the data-group="3d" to the <img> tag that has a 3d image. Delete the data-group from <figure> tag. Then try alert( $('[data-group="3d"]').length );

Comment: Thanks, I ll add a new class to figure tag

Comment: Great.. Mark this resolved if you are through. Thanks ;)